# Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation does not make sense

Tags: typescript

I have the following code that should throw a typescript error:

```
export class Alpha {
  getA(alpha: string | number);
  getA(alpha: number) {
    const beta = alpha * 2;
    console.log(beta);
  }
}

const a = new Alpha();

a.getA('1254s');
```

The result in the console is `NaN`, because in the example above the override **is** compatible with the implementation **BUT** the implementation **is not** compatible with the overrride, which leads to TS **not** prompting me that `alpha` can actually be a `string` as well, which leads to me making this mistake in my code.

Am I missing something or is it really a bug / limitation of TS?

Comment: What happens when you remove async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that both @aaronlukacs and @captain-yossarian answers are missing the OP's point.

The OP is claiming about the fact that by writing this implementation:

```
async getA(alpha: number) {
    const beta = alpha * 2;
    console.log(beta);
  }
```

TypeScript is not prompting that `alpha` could actually be a string as well due to the overload signature `getA(alpha: string | number)`. So while calling the function this way: `const result = a.getA('1254s');` is perfectly valid, this line on the implementation: `const beta = alpha * 2;` should instead raise an error.

This seems indeed to be a limitation of TS in overloading functions, as could be inferred from a couple of advices you can find in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

> The signature of the implementation is not visible from the outside.
> When writing an overloaded function, you should always have two or
> more signatures above the implementation of the function.

> Always prefer parameters with union types instead of overloads when
> possible

A version of the OP's code compliant with these advices should look like this:

```
class Alpha {
  getA(alpha: string): void;
  getA(alpha: number): void;
  getA(alpha: number | string): void {
    const beta = alpha * 2;
    console.log(beta);
  }
}
```

which indeed raises an error on `alpha * 2`, or like this:

```
class Alpha {
  getA(alpha: number | string): void {
    const beta = alpha * 2;
    console.log(beta);
  }
}
```

where overloading is removed at all.

Note that the two versions are not entirely equivalent: in the first version `getA()` wouldn't accept a value of type `string | number`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in your example is invalid. You always need to explicitly define return type in your overloads.

```js
export class Alpha {
  getA(alpha: string | number): void; // <--- return type should be defined
  async getA(alpha: number) {
    const beta = alpha * 2;
    console.log(beta);
  }
}

const a = new Alpha();

const result = await a.getA('1254s');
```

TypeScript allows you to pass a `string` because you allowed it in your overloading.

If you don't want to allow `string`, just remove overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function overloading is a bit different compared to OOP languages, it can differentiate function signatures only by the name and the number of function arguments.

You are not overloading the function, simply implementing your getA function, as you would with an interface:

```
interface AlphaI{
getA(alpha: string | number): void;

}
class Alpha implements AlphaI{
   getA(alpha: number) {
    const beta = alpha * 2;
    console.log(beta);
  }
}
const a = new Alpha();

const result = a.getA('1254s');
```

The implementation of the function is valid, because number is either number or string, but in this case TS throws a `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'` error, because it considers the implementation in the class Alpha.